# expanding decorator manually crashes the program later

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I have been trying to understand Flask decorators from a language standpoint. Based on my understanding of decorators, method1, method2 and method3 should be have identically.

```
# server.py
#
# callback-based server response, based on official Flask docs:
# http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/8/
#
# to run server:
#   gunicorn server:app --bind localhost:5000
#
# to test:
#   curl http://localhost:5000/1 -X POST -d POST_DATA -H "Content-Type: application/json"
#   curl http://localhost:5000/2 -X POST -d POST_DATA -H "Content-Type: application/json"
#   curl http://localhost:5000/3 -X POST -d POST_DATA -H "Content-Type: application/json"




from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)


def callback(*args, **kwargs):
    print "post_data=", request.data
    return "RESPONSE\n", 200

def wrapper(f):
    return callback




# method 1
@app.route('/1', methods=['POST'])
@wrapper
def method1():
    pass


# method 2
@app.route("/2", methods=['POST'])
def method2():
    return wrapper(method2)


# method 3
@app.route("/3", methods=['POST'])
def method3():
    return callback
```

However, when I run the 3 curl tests, the results are different. In the case of /1 and /2, the program crashes shortly after printing "post_data=POST_DATA":

```
post_data= POST_DATA
[2017-08-03 15:20:26,625] ERROR in app: Exception on /3 [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1630, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1740, in make_response
    rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 885, in force_type
    response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 903, in run_wsgi_app
    buffer.append(next(app_iter))
StopIteration
```

Notice that it died in Flask after completely exiting my app.route method.

Some basic research suggests that others have encountered this "StopIteration" problem:
https://github.com/getsentry/raven-python/issues/514
but not in such a trivial example, nor in any example using the response callback pattern on the official flask docs (http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/8/). Therefore I conclude that the problem is not in Flask itself, but in my understanding of decorators.

I don't understand how the 3 methods could possibly be doing different things. All of them are referencing the exact same identical "callback" function. Either they successfully fed this function over to Flask, or they didn't.

If they did feed the function to Flask... then the test is successful.
If they didn't feed the function to Flask... then how on earth is Flask calling the function to print "post_data=POST_DATA"?

The behavior appears to be entirely illogical.

(Or I am misunderstanding what a decorator does, and it is actually putting some kind of hidden metadata into the result and Flask is being evil and checking that metadata in undocumented ways.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a basic problem with your code. First, recall that a decorator...

```
@decorator
def myfunction():
    pass
```

...is exactly equivalent to:

```
def _myfunction():
    pass
myfunction = decorator(_myfunction)
```

With this in mind, you will note that in method 2, you are return a function, not an iterator:

```
@app.route("/2", methods=['POST'])
def method2():
    return wrapper(method2)
```

Remember that the return value of `wrapper` is a *function*:

```
def wrapper(f):
    return callback
```

So here you're effectively doing:

```
@app.route("/2", methods=['POST'])
def method2():
    return callback
```

You're returning a single value (the function) rather than tuple.  You actually want:

```
@app.route("/2", methods=['POST'])
def method2():
    return wrapper(method2)()
```

And similarly for method 3:

```
@app.route("/3", methods=['POST'])
def method3():
    return callback()
```

In both cases, you need to actually *call* the `callback` function.

Comment: No, method1 is not calling the callback. Add an assertion to callback and you will see that it is not being called from method1. Flask is calling the callback in all 3 methods.

Comment: To summarize: the decorator is doing SOMETHING that makes Flask happy, but it's not calling the callback. The callback is being called later, through the werkzeug/test module.

Comment: Of course method 1 is calling the callback. That's why it works, and why when you access `/1` you see `RESPONSE`.  I would suggest deleting these comments and moving them into your question, where you can format them such that they are readable. Note that I am not claiming that the *decorator* is calling `callback`; please take a second look at this answer (and note that the code presented here works).

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I was looking at the wrong stack dump. And was thrown off because Flask was calling the callback in all 3 cases (why it doesn't print a more helpful error message is another issue...). I tried many examples and it works the way you say.